# USPTO Services: Patent Searches & Patent Examinations

Tags: uspto, patent-services, fees

The USPTO has a ['menu' of service](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/fees-and-payment/uspto-fee-schedule)s that one can purchase.  I suspect that a patent search and exam is required when a utility patent:

1. Why and when is each mandatory service performed?  What are said mandatory services for a utility patent application?
2. When are said service fees due? At filing of the NPA?
3. If I do not understand the description of the line-item service (Reissue?), where is a good online resource to find clarification?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [fee schedule](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/fees-and-payment/uspto-fee-schedule) for the USPTO's services. There are fees to file a PPA and more expensive fees for an NPA. Generally, fees are lower for smaller entities. There is a micro-entity fee and a small entity fee for most fee items. There are fees related to appeals, to requesting an IPR, and to a reissue application.

Generally fees are due at filing although, depending upon the fee, they can be delayed for an additional surcharge.

There is a process called reissue that allows the patent owner to declare that their granted patent is deficient in some way and get a re-examination, often involving amending the claims. You can't expand beyond the original disclosure and the defect can be "I didn't claim as broadly as I could have claimed."